# Serve static content with webflux and multiple wildcards

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, static-content

I want to serve react app with routes from Spring Boot with WebFlux and functional routing.

I'm trying to implement following rules:

1. There are few `/api` endpoints that should be routed with functions.
2. Everything starting with the `/static` should serve static content.
3. Everything else should serve `index.html`

I've added following function:

```java
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(Handler1 handler1,
                                                  Handler2 handler2) {
        HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> indexPage = (req) -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(new ClassPathResource("public/index.html"));
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                              .GET("/api/route1", handler1)
                              .POST("/api/route2", handler2)
                              .resources("/static/**", new ClassPathResource("/public/**"))
                              .GET("/**", indexPage)
                              .build();
    }
```

API routes work fine, but when I try to get any static content I get index page.

Changing `/**` to `/` allows me get static content as well as index page by `/` route.

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-routes) route with static has should be checked first, but somehow it becomes overridden with the last wildcard route.

> Router functions are evaluated in order: if the first route does not match, the second is evaluated, and so on. Therefore, it makes sense to declare more specific routes before general ones.

What am I missing?

Comment: i just did a simple search in the docs and found this, dont ask me about it https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-config-static-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. `ClassPathResource` accepts path to location. No need for wildcards.

With `GET("/*", indexPage)` static resources were served not using `resources("/static/**", new ClassPathResource("/public/**"))`, but with the default webflux configuration `spring.webflux.static-path-pattern`.

Correct router function declaration:

```java
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(Handler1 handler1,
                                                  Handler2 handler2) {
        HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> indexPage = (req) -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(new ClassPathResource("public/index.html"));
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                              .GET("/api/route1", handler1)
                              .POST("/api/route2", handler2)
                              .resources("/static/**", new ClassPathResource("/public/"))
                              .GET("/**", indexPage)
                              .build();
    }
```